# Can't get same instance by using RegisterInstance

Tags: prism, unity-container

I want register ShellModel with container, so I can resolve it in ViewModel whcich in another module, then I can change the window style in the ViewModel. But I can't get the same instance of ShellModel in ViewModel, it always return new instance of ShellModel. So I write a simple test below, I'm confused about that.

```
public Shell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var shellModel = new ShellModel();
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterInstance<ShellModel>(shellModel);
        Console.WriteLine(container.Resolve<ShellModel>().GetHashCode());//41837403
        Console.WriteLine(container.Resolve<ShellModel>().GetHashCode());//41837403
        IUnityContainer newcontainer = new UnityContainer();
        Console.WriteLine(newcontainer.Resolve<ShellModel>().GetHashCode());//3634967
        Console.WriteLine(newcontainer.Resolve<ShellModel>().GetHashCode());//29355815
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using two containers, and as you haven't registered an instance in the second container, Unity is returning a new instance of Shell(View?)Model.